# How To Update Upload Size on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: docker, nginx, digital-ocean, fastapi, uvicorn

I am using digitalocean app platform and successfuly deployed my app using docker and circleci. I am using FastAPI frame with uvicorn as a web server. I am facing a problem where I am trying to send a request with large file size (might exceed 700 MB) and I am receiving a response which says: 413 Request Entity Too Large. How can I increase upload size in digitalocean apps?

Comment: The maximum size of a request can be a server configuration (it the case on IIS for example)